# Exception handling once an object has been created

Tags: c++, class, exception

I am a bit confused on where I should throw an exception and where I should catch it. Right now I am throwing an invalid_argument as soon as someone creates a book with an invalid page.

In my main function I am then creating a book with an invalid page and I am catching that exception and writing out the message. Is this how you are supposed to do it? Because right now I am only catching one single instance of a book. If I tried to create another book outside the try catch block with an invalid page I woudnt be able to catch it. Is this really necessary? Is this how I'm supposed to handle exceptions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

 class Book
  {
  public:
    string title {};
    string author {};
    int pages {};
    int readers {};

    Book(string const& t, string const& a, int const p)
        : title{t}, author{a}, pages{p}, readers{0}
    {
      if (pages <= 0)
        throw invalid_argument ("Invalid page!");
    }

    void print() const
    {
    cout << "Title: " << title << "\nAuthor: " << author
         << "\nPages: " << pages << "\nReaders: " << readers << endl;
    }
    
  };

int main()
{
  try
  {
    Book book_1("Harry Potter", "JK Rowling", 0);
  }
  catch(const exception& e)
  {
    cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << endl;
  }
  
  //book_1.print(); 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need a try every time you create a book.

Comment: You can create any number of books inside the try block and only write the catch block once

Comment: @user253751 It's not really a good idea. If the first book raises an exception, the code will enter the catch block and all the others will be skipped and thus never processed. It is better to treat errors independently. Defining functions to perform the exception handling may help to not have to bother with it everytime.

Comment: @Fareanor If the exception is thrown then whatever you are trying to do is wrong. Why would you want to keep doing something that doesn't work? The whole point of exceptions is so if something doesn't work, the program can stop whatever it's doing and go home early.

Comment: @user253751 Nope, it only means that the book that raised the exception is invalid, not that the others are too. You should be able to process the valid books anyway. "The whole point of exceptions" handling is so you can **handle** the exceptions so that the program will be able to go through (and not "go home")

Comment: @Fareanor If it's not what you want your program to do, then don't use exceptions that way. You should write the program that does what you want it to do. The point of exceptions is definitely to break out of a series of steps.

Comment: @Fareanor The whole point of exceptions is *presumptive workflow*, not per-line error handling. You have code that needs three distinct Book objects. You can put them *all* in the same try block and know that, once the line declaring the second is reached, it is only because the first was successful; likewise from the second to third, etc. If you're using exceptions for per-line error handling you're driving nails with a screwdriver.

Comment: I disagree with you guys, if for example I want to handle a bunch of input data, and for example, store them into a database or whatever, I want the valid data to be stored and the invalid to be skipped with a proper error handling (for example a flag, a log message, send an email, etc...) to notify what data could not be properly processed **without penalizing the whole process nor the valid data registering/processing**.

Comment: [Here is a minimal example of what I mean](https://godbolt.org/z/n5n7nEGo6)

Comment: @Fareanor No worries, mate. We certainly don't have to agree. I expect situationally either perspective of this bleeds over into the other anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should catch and handle the exception where it makes sense for the program.

First of all, your program *always* throws the exception independent of input, because the `0` is hard-coded. This doesn't seem to be a use case for an exception. This seems to be a logic error and so it should be considered a bug that needs fixing. Why should it make sense to try to create a guaranteed invalid book?

But let's suppose the number of pages is given by user input. Then the next issue would be that you can't print a book that failed to be created. So `book_1.print();` must be part of the `try` block.

Let's suppose you have a second book `book_2`, also created from input from the user. You need to ask yourself then whether it makes sense for the program logic to continue creating and using the second book if creating the first one failed.

If failing to create the first book means that there is no point in continuing with the second book, then just put everything in one `try` block, e.g.:

```
try
{
  Book book_1(/*...*/);
  book_1.print();

  Book book_2(/*...*/);
  book_2.print();
}
catch(const exception& e)
{
  cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << endl;
}
```

When either of the book creations fail, the program will continue executing in the `catch` handler and then after it, skipping over the rest of the book creations and printing. But if `book_1` didn't throw on construction, then it will be printed before `book_2` is "checked".

Maybe you would want

```
try
{
  Book book_1(/*...*/);
  Book book_2(/*...*/);

  book_1.print();
  book_2.print();
}
catch(const exception& e)
{
  cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << endl;
}
```

With this the program will not print any book if creation of either book fails.

If it does make sense for the program to continue execution if creation of the first book failed, then use two `try`/`catch` statements to handle the errors individually:

```
try
{
  Book book_1(/*...*/);
  book_1.print();
}
catch(const exception& e)
{
  cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << endl;
}

try
{
  Book book_2(/*...*/);
  book_2.print();
}
catch(const exception& e)
{
  cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << endl;
}
```

You might want to consider using a function or arrays and loops to make this less redundant, for example if the goal is to just repeatedly take user input, create a book and then print it, a simple loop will be helpful:

```
while(true)
{
  try
  {
    /* take user input here */
    if(/* some exit condition */)
    {
        break;
    }
    Book book(/* arguments from user input */);
    book.print();
  }
  catch(const exception& e)
  {
    cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << endl;
  }
}
```

This loop will run until the exit condition is satisfied. If any standard exception (from book creation or the input operation) is thrown, the exception message will be printed and the loop continues anew.

(As an additional note: In all of the examples above *all* exceptions inherited from `std::exception` thrown in the `try` blocks will be caught. This means not only the `invalid_argument` exception from the book creation, but e.g. any exception thrown by `.print()` or the input handling. You may not want to handle these the same way as the invalid book creation. For example an exception from input operations could mean that there is no way for the program to continue the loop. Therefore it makes sense to use a custom class (maybe inherited from `std::invalid_argument`) for the `throw` in `Book`'s constructor and catch only that. This way you can handle the invalid book creation specifically.)

Comment: A function would be good. But the function should be outside the class, right?

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie Depends on what exactly you want to do. The code in your question doesn't really do anything useful yet since it doesn't take any input. Depending on what the actual program is supposed to do (i.e. what is supposed to be the input and corresponding output), there may be different strategies to structure the code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you call a function that may throw an exception, at some point, you will need to handle it. The way to do it is to catch the exception.

> *Is it really necessary?*

Well it depends. If in your case you ensure that you won't create your objects with invalid arguments, you don't need to catch an exception that'll never be raised.
Exception handling is **only required** when you don't know (you have no guarantee), for example when the page parameter is given from a **user input**, a **file** or anything that is unknown/not predictable/not controlled by the code base.

---

<s>That being said, in your case you can do even better, just replace:</s>

```
int pages;
```

with:

```
unsigned int pages;
```

And then it would not be possible to give an invalid number anymore. Which means you can completely remove the exception handling off your code.

<sub>***The above proposal didn't take into account that `0` is considered invalid as well.***</sub>

Comment: The `Book` class considers `0` pages also as invalid.

Comment: @user17732522 Oh right, I was too quick !